# How to handle JSON persistently between JavaScript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, persistent

I am currently working with a server that holds many JSON cache files that need to be accessed each time the user needs to get more data. I have the JSON files ordered by most recent data first. Here is how the whole system should work: I need to access each file (say 3) at the same time and compare their times then I will make a JSON file and send it to JavaScript to be process and printed to the page. The dilemma I am having is, after I get the data the first, second, so on time I need to save the last position I got each item in each file, so I can continue loading in the next most recent data when the user scrolls to the bottom on the content I have loaded for them. The method I have come up with is saving each location (a number) as a session for the user. The problem is that the user will need to access the entire set of JSON files to continue where they left off. This seems very inefficient and will become cumbersome the more JSON files there are.

For clarification here are the steps I was able to come up with:

PHP section:

1. decode each JSON file - this part feels very inefficient to load
   every time
2. loop to 20 items{  compare the times on each first item in the files
   add the most recent data to an array or some structure and inc that
   files count }
3. save the current locations and files in session variables
   (filea1.JSON could run over into filea2.JSON)

JavaScript:

1. Parse the JSON Print all data to the page
2. If the user scrolls to the bottom of the data{ make another PHP call
   }

repeat till out of data in files or user leaves the page.

I need the loading of the files to be efficient the rest of the steps are straight forward for me, but what I can think of is to keep the JSON in PHP persistent, so I do not need to load all the data once again. This or I need to load the data continuing where I left off.

I could be completely wrong about the data needing to persist, but I am relatively new to PHP and don't know that many tricks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the data to be json files on the server? Any other applications using them? Otherwise, this is where I would use a database. If it is simple data you could use SQLite (which is just a file on the server as well). Then you can use the ID or a date-column to handle the paging.

Comment: +1 for using a database. Do all your json files have the same number of entries? If so, you could calculate what file to start parsing, skipping previous ones. Alternatively, store your offset in two fields: file, and 'offset' in that file.

Comment: @Magnus The data is cached data coming from an api. Now that I think about it I could store it in a table. My only thing is that I imagine some of the user data I get from the api could be upwards of 3000 data units each containing time, numbers, and user data. If I made a table for each api then stored user data in the tables along with their user id. I feel the table would get out of control. Maybe I haven't normalized tables in so long that I fail to realize how I could have a separate table for each users api data.

Comment: @Kenney Each file works as so: I have all the user data from one api ordered by time per JSON file. Each file has 200 pieces of repetitive data. I specifically used the word server to try and note that this not part of my servers database,but I am trying now to figure out how I can store large amounts of data in the database and efficiently query it for a specific user. Lets say 10k people are on the site with 1000 pieces of api data each. That is 10m rows and I imagine this is the wrong way to make the tables. So I need to determine how to have users access their own special table or data

Comment: If the data sets are that large, you shouldn't use files. IO is usually the slowest part of a server. Since I don't have a full grasp on how the files or your application works, I can't give any recommendation on a database scheme, but that would be what I would look into.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The data is the data for the users posts on a given api. The application is used to show the users data and give analytics on that data. An example might be the number of views they got in the last week. Thank you for the help I will be looking into this thoroughly. I just need the tables to be unique for each user, but also I may not want them to be separated just psudo-separated (similar to how foreign keys work). I may just be too fuzzy on my sql and need to review my books on it I feel I am just over thinking this or how much sql can handle.

Comment: I realize I should use one table per api to hold all the data for that api, then index the table to allow higher performance. Thank you for the comments. I do not even remember why I was thinking in terms of files instead of tables (maybe I thought the size was too much?).

Comment: It's easy to run with the first solution that pops in to your head. :)